# Get the Average of Two drop down values in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

How can I watch the model (without using ng change) of two select boxes if selected should calculate the average and display the answer in the text field: for example

HTML I:

```
<select ng-model="box1" ng-options="item for item in boxA"></select>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.boxA=[1,2,3,4,5];
```

HTML II:

```
<select ng-model="box2" ng-options="item for item in boxB"></select>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.boxA=[6,7,8,9,10];
```

Text Box:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="answer">
```

Comment: what have you tried? and I assume that the second `$scope.boxA` is meant to be `$scope.boxB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better and more Angular way, you can use $watchCollection instead:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[box1, box2]',function(newValues,oldValues){
    console.log('Box1: '+newValues[0]+', Box2: '+newValues[1]);

    $scope.answer =  (parseInt(newValues[0]) + parseInt(newValues[1])/2; //(or replace 2 with newValues.length if you plan to add more models into watch and get an average of more;)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use ng-change, my suggestion is to make an interval to check the values in your controller.

```
$interval(function() {
    if($scope.box1 && $scope.box2) {
      $scope.answer =  (parseInt($scope.box1) + parseInt($scope.box2))/2
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch `$scope.box1` and `$scope.box2` with something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('box1', function(value){
    $scope.answer = calculateAverage(value, $scope.box2);
});
$scope.$watch('box2', function(value){
    $scope.answer = calculateAverage(value, $scope.box1);
});
```

take a look a this fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/manzapanza/wm8s5vmz/1/